# get the values in the bracket or double quotes pandas string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this i wanted to get the values in the square bracket

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','102','103','104'],'Text':["""{"x":["8"]""","""{"y":["7"]}""","""["ww"]""","""""10"]"""""]})
```

**Wanted Output:**

[image]

Comment: did you miss the square bracket in the last row of text? if yes, check below aswers, if no, please let us know

Comment: no the data is like that.it is not missed.

Answer (score 1):

you can Use:

```
df['text_new']=df.Text.str.extract(r"\[(.*?)\]", expand=False)
print(df)

  User         Text text_new
0  101   {"x":["8"]      "8"
1  102  {"y":["7"]}      "7"
2  103       ["ww"]     "ww"
3  104      "["10"]     "10"
```

Comment: check 3rd row 'ww'

Comment: @Wen-Ben fixed now.

Comment: Didn't see you had the same answer.

Comment: @MohitMotwani thats fine, i dont mind, you can undelete. :)

Comment: It's just redundant :p

Comment: Thanks. but for last row its giving nan i need values and also needs to remove quotes in final output.

Comment: @KumarAK how about `df['text_new']=df.Text.str.extract(r"\[(.*?)\]").fillna(df.Text.str.extract('(\d+)'))` ?

Comment: Thanks it works only for digits in case of text it will give NAN only.